# Database creation Failed in Genexus Offline android app

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

I have a couple issues with an Offline Android app developed in Genexus 16 U11 in C# Environment and SQL 2017.

First of all, when I press Build All to any changes to the OfflineDatabase object, Genexus' Navigation View marks it has an error, but it doesn't specify where it is or in what consist the error (and the build log doesn't mention any error either). I also tried to quote or straight remove all the code in said object, so it can be built clean, and still get an error without any clue about what may be going on.

On the other hand, the app also throws an "Database creation Failed" error before the app starts and also I can't find any message regarding this specifically in the ADB monitor, but for some reason Genexus still manages to build.

Any ideas about what may be happening? do you guys need more information about this issue?

thanks beforehand

Comment: Did you try Build -> Create Offline Database ->  Main ? do you get an error there?

Comment: Yes I did that too and still get the Database creation Failed error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have just solved this issue.

When I made an Rebuild All, i've noticed at the output log had a line that said

```
GeneXus Java Make v1.0
Ruta de acceso no válida
0 archivo(s) copiado(s)
.\..\gxcommonclass\. : no existe tal archivo o directorio
```

found out (throughout another Offline Mobile KB) that there was a gxcommonclass folder in [EnironmentFolder]\mobile\Android, but in the one I was having trouble didn't had one, only a gxcommon folder.

Manually created an gxcommonclass, copied the contents of gxcommon to gxcommonclass and now it works and the message is

```
GeneXus Java Make v1.0
Build succeeded.
Creating Client Access Package
179 archivo(s) copiado(s)
```

I hope this helps to anyone in the future

Answer (score 0):

This problem is with Android compilation in a Windows 11 machine.

More details here:
https://www.genexus.com/en/developers/websac?data=50349

In the link you can find file you need to copy to solve the problem. In v17u2 and above the fix is already include in Genexus.

Best,